# Call Powershell from Command Prompt Relative Path

Tags: powershell

I'm calling a PS script from Command Prompt using the following line

```
powershell "& 'c:/script.ps1'"
```

However I need the script to be relative to the command prompt window. So if command prompt was looking at `C:` then the script would effectively be

```
powershell "& 'script.ps1'"
```

Is there a way to inject the relative path?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
powershell "& '%cd%\script.ps1'"
```

or if you mean to use the directory from which the batch file was launched in the powershell script then you would use a parameter by putting this type of line at the start of your PS script...

```
param([string]$Directory)
```

Then populating it from the command line invocation like...

```
Powershell C:\script.ps1 -Directory %cd%
```

Answer (score 0):

To inject the relative path, where you start your batch file you have to write

```
powershell "& '%~dp0\script.ps1'"
```